# Make a test for _observer - Polymer unit tests

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an element `<my-elem1>` which has a property `elements` and an `_observer` function in `attached` function.

```js
attached: function () {
      var self = this;
      this._observer = Polymer.dom(this).observeNodes( function(info) {
        nodesToAdd = info.addedNodes.filter(function(node){
            return node.nodeName == 'MY-ELEM2'; // to get rig of #text nodes
          })
        nodesToAdd.forEach(function(elem) {
          self.push('elements', elem.asObject());
        });
      });
    }
```

where `elements` is defined as:

```js
    elements: {
      type: Array,
      notify: true,
      value: function() {
        return [];
      }
    },
```

Now I am trying to write test to check if this _observer is indeed pushing the `elem`'s in the `elements` array. My tests file looks something like the following:

```html
<test-fixture id="my-elem1-fixture">
  <template>
    <my-elem1>
      <my-elem2 foo="1"></my-elem2>
      <my-elem2 foo="2"></my-elem2>
      <my-elem2 foo="3"></my-elem2>
      <my-elem2 foo="4"></my-elem2>
    </my-elem1>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
  suite('my-elem', function() {
    var myEl;

    setup(function() {
      myEl = fixture('my-elem1-fixture');
    });

    test('checks the "elements" array', function() {
      assert(myEl.elements.length, 4);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Now this test is not passing. The value of myEl.points.length is 0. I wonder why is the _observer is not getting called. Even it's not allowing me to call myEl._observer, giving some error.

How can I write the tests? Also how do I test that initially the length of `elements` array was 0?

Comment: In <my-elem1> do you have a <content> part?
And do you even need an observer in this case? Since you don't use the info object and instead queries for all children on each change, it seems to me if/when you add something to <content>, your array will grow with all children again. But maybe just simplified code?

Comment: Hey @Bulan, I have changed the code. Now it uses info object to update the array. Is there any better way to do it add these nodes to the array without the observer? How do I write test? Also I couldn't find any source which explains what are the `#text`, or in general #something, nodes that keeps on coming in between and which I have to filter (there is a question regarding #text [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204949/how-to-get-rid-of-text-elelment-when-use-polymer-dom-api)).

Comment: Do you have a <content> tag somewhere at all?Maybe easier if you could you provide a jsfiddle or similar?